# Visual isssue with Red line in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am legally blind.  i have a visual issue in android studio.
i set most of my fonts to bold.
but, the squiggly red line under any incorrect
code would be easier to see if it were also bold.
is there any way in android studio to make the red
line bold?

Comment: I have no idea if that's possible, but I added the `android-studio` tag so that someone who does know can find this question more easily